# bad shape array after convertition from h5 to tflite

Tags: keras, retinanet

I trained a model via keras retinanet (by fizyr).
I converted it to .tflite but ran into issues when viewing the .tflite template information
Model informations:

tflife_input_details = tflife_model.get_input_details()

```
[{'name': 'input_1', 'index': 0, 'shape': array([1, 1, 1, 3], dtype=int32), 'shape_signature': 
array([-1, -1, -1,  3], dtype=int32), 'dtype': <class 'numpy.float32'>, 'quantization': (0.0, 
0), 'quantization_parameters': {'scales': array([], dtype=float32), 'zero_points': array([], 
dtype=int32), 'quantized_dimension': 0}, 'sparsity_parameters': {}}]
```

tflife_output_details = tflife_model.get_output_details()

```
[{'name': 'Identity', 'index': 354, 'shape': array([1, 1, 4], dtype=int32), 'shape_signature': 
array([-1, -1,  4], dtype=int32), 'dtype': <class 'numpy.float32'>, 'quantization': (0.0, 0), 
'quantization_parameters': {'scales': array([], dtype=float32), 'zero_points': array([], 
dtype=int32), 'quantized_dimension': 0}, 'sparsity_parameters': {}}, {'name': 'Identity_1', 
'index': 344, 'shape': array([1, 1, 1], dtype=int32), 'shape_signature': array([-1, -1,  1], 
 dtype=int32), 'dtype': <class 'numpy.float32'>, 'quantization': (0.0, 0), 
'quantization_parameters': {'scales': array([], dtype=float32), 'zero_points': array([], 
dtype=int32), 'quantized_dimension': 0}, 'sparsity_parameters': {}}]
```

Convert model to .tflite

```
import tensorflow as tf
from keras_retinanet.models import load_model
loaded_model = load_model("snapshots/resnet50_csv_10.h5", backbone_name='resnet50')
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(loaded_model)
tflite_model = converter.convert()
with tf.io.gfile.GFile('final.tflite', 'wb') as f:
  f.write(tflite_model)
```

Training:

```
Model: "retinanet"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)            [(None, None, None,  0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv1 (Conv2D)                  (None, None, None, 6 9408        input_1[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
bn_conv1 (BatchNormalization)   (None, None, None, 6 256         conv1[0][0]                      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv1_relu (Activation)         (None, None, None, 6 0           bn_conv1[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
pool1 (MaxPooling2D)            (None, None, None, 6 0           conv1_relu[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
res2a_branch2a (Conv2D)         (None, None, None, 6 4096        pool1[0][0]                      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
bn2a_branch2a (BatchNormalizati (None, None, None, 6 256         res2a_branch2a[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
res2a_branch2a_relu (Activation (None, None, None, 6 0           bn2a_branch2a[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
padding2a_branch2b (ZeroPadding (None, None, None, 6 0           res2a_branch2a_relu[0][0]        
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
res2a_branch2b (Conv2D)         (None, None, None, 6 36864       padding2a_branch2b[0][0]         
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
bn2a_branch2b (BatchNormalizati (None, None, None, 6 256         res2a_branch2b[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
res2a_branch2b_relu (Activation (None, None, None, 6 0           bn2a_branch2b[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
res2a_branch2c (Conv2D)         (None, None, None, 2 16384       res2a_branch2b_relu[0][0]        
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
res2a_branch1 (Conv2D)          (None, None, None, 2 16384       pool1[0][0]                      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
bn2a_branch2c (BatchNormalizati (None, None, None, 2 1024        res2a_branch2c[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
bn2a_branch1 (BatchNormalizatio (None, None, None, 2 1024        res2a_branch1[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
res2a (Add)                     (None, None, None, 2 0           bn2a_branch2c[0][0]              
                                                                 bn2a_branch1[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
res2a_relu (Activation)         (None, None, None, 2 0           res2a[0][0]                      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
res2b_branch2a (Conv2D)         (None, None, None, 6 16384       res2a_relu[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
bn2b_branch2a (BatchNormalizati (None, None, None, 6 256         res2b_branch2a[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
res2b_branch2a_relu (Activation (None, None, None, 6 0           bn2b_branch2a[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
padding2b_branch2b (ZeroPadding (None, None, None, 6 0           res2b_branch2a_relu[0][0]        
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
res2b_branch2b (Conv2D)         (None, None, None, 6 36864       padding2b_branch2b[0][0]         
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
bn2b_branch2b (BatchNormalizati (None, None, None, 6 256         res2b_branch2b[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
res2b_branch2b_relu (Activation (None, None, None, 6 0           bn2b_branch2b[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
res2b_branch2c (Conv2D)         (None, None, None, 2 16384       res2b_branch2b_relu[0][0]        
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
bn2b_branch2c (BatchNormalizati (None, None, None, 2 1024        res2b_branch2c[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
...               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
C4_reduced (Conv2D)             (None, None, None, 2 262400      res4f_relu[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
P4_merged (Add)                 (None, None, None, 2 0           P5_upsampled[0][0]               
                                                                 C4_reduced[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
P4_upsampled (UpsampleLike)     (None, None, None, 2 0           P4_merged[0][0]                  
                                                                 res3d_relu[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
C3_reduced (Conv2D)             (None, None, None, 2 131328      res3d_relu[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
P6 (Conv2D)                     (None, None, None, 2 4718848     res5c_relu[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
P3_merged (Add)                 (None, None, None, 2 0           P4_upsampled[0][0]               
                                                                 C3_reduced[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
C6_relu (Activation)            (None, None, None, 2 0           P6[0][0]                         
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
P3 (Conv2D)                     (None, None, None, 2 590080      P3_merged[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
P4 (Conv2D)                     (None, None, None, 2 590080      P4_merged[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
P5 (Conv2D)                     (None, None, None, 2 590080      C5_reduced[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
P7 (Conv2D)                     (None, None, None, 2 590080      C6_relu[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
regression_submodel (Functional (None, None, 4)      2443300     P3[0][0]                         
                                                                 P4[0][0]                         
                                                                 P5[0][0]                         
                                                                 P6[0][0]                         
                                                                 P7[0][0]                         
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
classification_submodel (Functi (None, None, 1)      2381065     P3[0][0]                         
                                                                 P4[0][0]                         
                                                                 P5[0][0]                         
                                                                 P6[0][0]                         
                                                                 P7[0][0]                         
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
regression (Concatenate)        (None, None, 4)      0           regression_submodel[0][0]        
                                                                 regression_submodel[1][0]        
                                                                 regression_submodel[2][0]        
                                                                 regression_submodel[3][0]        
                                                                 regression_submodel[4][0]        
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
classification (Concatenate)    (None, None, 1)      0           classification_submodel[0][0]    
                                                                 classification_submodel[1][0]    
                                                                 classification_submodel[2][0]    
                                                                 classification_submodel[3][0]    
                                                                 classification_submodel[4][0]    
==================================================================================================
Total params: 36,382,957
Trainable params: 12,821,805
Non-trainable params: 23,561,152
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
None
```

As shown, the array shape entry is (1, 1, 1, 3).
How is it possible? Did I do something wrong with the conversion? Does this model currently not work in inference?

UPDATE: The structure of my converted model:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/m444F.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I think that this will works for you :

So first of all, you should install `keras_retinanet` using pip

```
pip install keras_retinanet
```

And than execute this script

```
import tensorflow as tf
from keras_retinanet.models import load_model

loaded_model = load_model("snapshots/resnet50_csv_10.h5", backbone_name='resnet50')
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(loaded_model)
tflite_model = converter.convert()
with tf.io.gfile.GFile('final.tflite', 'wb') as f:
  f.write(tflite_model)
```

Comment: I using google colab.
I tried to use that code but i get this error:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.contrib'

Comment: What's the version of Tensorflow that you are using?

Comment: Tensorflow 2.x.x (I don't remember the exact version, but is tensorflow v2)

Comment: Could you give me the exact version ?

Comment: tensorflow 2.6. (i'm using google colab with GPU)

Comment: Please see the update and try my solution again

Comment: The conversion was successful, showing me this message:
INFO:tensorflow:Assets written to: /tmp/tmp50ne6vo0/assets
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/utils/generic_utils.py:497: CustomMaskWarning: Custom mask layers require a config and must override get_config. When loading, the custom mask layer must be passed to the custom_objects argument.
  category=CustomMaskWarning)
But the initial problem remains the same

Comment: The first problem should be solved , I have already tested on Google Collab , but I didn't test yet the conversion because I don't have the model.

Comment: if it is not a problem we can contact you via email so I will send you the model: federico.frari1995@gmail.com

Comment: Could you tell me from where do you have downloaded the model?

Comment: https://github.com/fizyr/keras-retinanet
However I believe that before doing the conversion to .tflite, I should convert the .h5 model for inference

Comment: My .h5 model is with variable input size. How can i train my keras model with fix input size?